# PostBack OnTextChanged is triggering when unrelated button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net

On my page, I have:

- `txtCalendar`, an `asp:TextBox` used to enter a date, with an attached JQuery `datepicker`
- `btnSave`, an `asp:Button` to save the form
- `btnAdd`, an `asp:LinkButton` that opens a new form for a different part of the page.

When either button is clicked, `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is called *before* the `btnSave_Click` or `btnAdd_Click` function is called. `txtCalendar_TextChanged` shouldn't be called at all when these buttons are clicked - before *or* after.

It is possible that the JQuery `datepicker` is somehow causing this - when I comment out the code instantiating `datepicker` and binding it to the textbox, `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is *not* called.

Additionally, I have verified:

- Even when I prevent the `$(function() {}` script from running after a postback, the `txtCalendar_TextChanged` method is still called when a button is clicked
- I do not have any JavaScript that looks for the ID `#btnSave` or `#btnAdd` or anything that could match/respond to those IDs
- the `sender` for `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is my `txtCalendar` textbox
- `eventargs` for `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is empty (not sure if this is significant)
- the text in `txtCalendar` doesn't actually change (verified visually in the UI, not by adding code on the backend to check)
- `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is *not* called when I remove `OnTextChanged='txtCalendar_TextChanged'` (so - it *is* being called by `txtCalendar`, somehow...)
- `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is called even when I remove `AutoPostBack='true'`
- `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is called even when I disable the `btnSave_Click` function by commenting out `Handles btnSave.Click` (both buttons use `Handles btnX.Click` in the aspx.vb rather than `OnClick="btnX_Click"` in the aspx)
- `Page_Load` is hit before `txtCalendar_TextChanged`, but the first check is `If(Page.IsPostBack) Then Exit Sub` - the rest of `Page_Load` doesn't run (so - other backend functions are not being hit)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

In vb.net, I use `myDate.ToShortDateString` to set the initial value in `txtCalendar`.  `ToShortDateString` formats dates without leading zeroes, while `datepicker`'s default format does have leading zeroes

When `datepicker` is instantiated, it changes the date format in `txtCalendar`, but since this is done via code, it doesn't trigger a postback. When the user clicks a button and a postback is triggered, `txtCalendar_TextChanged` is also triggered because of the new date format (the text string has changed).

Changing `datepicker`'s `dateFormat` to `m/d/yy` fixed the problem.